# How to ignore an empty line from the keyboard in C

Tags: c

I'm struggling with what seems a trivial problem in C inputting data from the keyboard, but I'm a C noob (with some background in Java, though)

**What I need**: I need to type an *int* value from the keyboard (then press Enter), then I need the user to press Enter only without inputting anything, and then to type another *int* (and press Enter one more time).

**What I can do**:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
scanf("%d", &a);
skip_line_cool_function();
scanf("%d", &b);
printf("You have just entered: &d and &d", a, b);
```

As you can see, I don't know how to skip the line.

**What I have tried**: *scanf* entering a dummy C-string, but, as you know, when you enter nothing, it patiently waits for at least something to be entered.

**What I Googled**: I suspect that *fgets* can do the job, but honestly, I didn't understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: If you want control over lines, don't use `scanf()`; use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.  If you use `scanf()`, it will allow the user to enter an arbitrary amount of white space, including newlines, before the number.  You can write your function as `void skip_line_cool_function(int n) { int c; int i = 0; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && i < n) { if (c == '\n') i++; } }`.  You'd call it as `skip_line_cool_function(2);` to skip two newlines — the one after the first number, and the one for the blank line.  The UI doesn't sound very pleasant; forcing people to type blank lines is a bit problematic.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Actually, that's not UI, I didn't want to get into much detail, this is an UVa Online Judge problem input requirement (793, to be precise). I did that in Java and it seemed more or less simple, now I'm trying to boost my C/C++ skills because I'll need them later.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Read first integer */
do {
  if(!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) break;
} while( last_character_of(buffer) != '\n');
/* Read next integer */
```

Comment: This `do{...} while` skips one line `skip_line_cool_function()`.  If you need a line in between, you need it 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are this much rigid about the UI that the user will only press a single enter then why not do this?

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
scanf("%d", &a);
getchar(); /* this will get the enter pressed after entering a */
getchar(); /* this will get the enter for the blank line */
scanf("%d", &b);
printf("You have just entered: &d and &b", a, b);
```

Also the code snippet you've posted will result into compile error. `printf()` will need integer format specifier `%d` to work properly. Use this:

```
printf("You have just entered: %d and %d", a, b);
```

Comment: You're so much right, thanks, I edited that! And thank you for the idea!